# Border-left with a horizontal line to the right

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to make a border to the left that connects a horizontal line from the right. I'll show a sketch on how it should look like, and I need ideas on how to make it simple:

[image]

Thanks for many good solutions, the ones below worked fine.

Is there a simple way of making the borders on the left gradient, together with the horizontal line? Also how to fill these gaps? I am trying to make a timeline..

Comment: have you tried anything? show your code.

Comment: simple would be an image ;)

Answer (score 5):

looks like an `hr` tag redesigned use to me ,

a `border-left` and a background-gradient can fake this shape. you can use `calc()` to set `height` of middle line.

```css
hr {
  border:none;
  height:100px;
  border-left: solid 20px #DC5969;
  background:linear-gradient(to top, transparent calc(50% - 1px), #DC5969 calc(50% - 1px), #DC5969 calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px));/* makes a 2px height line */
    }
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom left, lightgray,turquoise); /* demo purpose, show transparency */
  }
```

```html
<hr/>
```

EDIT: question updated, still missing code :)

```css
hr {
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  width: auto;
  border: none;
  height: 100px;
  border-left: solid 20px #DC5969;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent calc(50% - 1px), #DC5969 calc(50% - 1px), #DC5969 calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px));
  /* makes a 2px height line */
}

div {
  margin: 0 auto auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}

section {
  display: table;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <hr/>
  <div>
    <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
    <h2>Header Level 2</h2>
    <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci,
      sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <hr/>
  <div>
    <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
    <h2>Header Level 2</h2>
    <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <hr/>
  <div>
    <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
    <h2>Header Level 2</h2>
    <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. ornare sit amet,
      wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

You can add class to `hr` or use `nth-child` to change colors example : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZWPQed

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in a single HTML node:

```
<style>
.you-name-it {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.you-name-it:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 1em;
  height: 200%;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>

// ...

<div class="you-name-it"></div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/odwgL86x/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like two `<divs>` on another might be your best bet. Just mess with the sizing of the secondary `div` `height`s and the width of the `margins`

Here is something I threw together really quick: https://jsfiddle.net/fsqu1dp7/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pseudo elements `:before` or `:after`.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/fu4yjvjz/

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code below

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
</div>
```

And the style declarations as follows.

```
.outer{
  border-left:20px solid;
  height:200px;
}

.inner{
   border-bottom:3px solid;
   height:100px;
}
```